# Oracle SQL pivot translation

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table as follows:

```
SNF                 SFCM        POOL            QUOTA
a                   US          eng         11
a                   US          sud         20
b                   UK          aau         30
```

But would like it to be displayed as follows:

```
SNF      SFCM        eng       sud     aau
a        US          11        20         
b        UK                            30
```

I have tried to use a pivot as follows

```
SELECT a.* FROM test
PIVOT
(
SUM(QUOTA) AS QUOTA
FOR pool
IN ('eng', 'sud', 'aau')
)
```

But can't seem to get the correct output.

Would anyone be able to advise me? Also, I was wondering if it was possible to use an SQL statement instead of `'eng', 'sud', 'aau'`. so `IN(select POOL from test)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as follows:

```
SELECT SNF, SFCM, eng_quota, sud_quota, aau_quota FROM nc_so1
PIVOT
(
SUM(QUOTA) AS QUOTA
FOR pool
IN ('eng' as eng, 'sud' as sud, 'aau' as aau)
)
```

Also it is not possible to generate a dynamic list using SQL AFAIK

Comment: It's PL/SQL, but you can use EXEC IMMEDIATE for your dynamic SQL.

Comment: @RobertCo There is no PL/SQL code in this answer. What is your point?

Answer (score 0):

Your original SQL gives the desired result (with minor changes):

```
SQL> with t (SNF, SFCM, POOL, QUOTA) as
  2  (
  3  select 'a','US','eng',11 from dual union all
  4  select 'a','US','sud',20 from dual union all
  5  select 'b','UK','aau',30 from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM t
  8  PIVOT
  9  (
 10  SUM(QUOTA)
 11  FOR (pool)
 12  IN ('eng' "ENG", 'sud' "SUD", 'aau' "AAU")
 13  )
 14  /

SNF SFCM        ENG        SUD        AAU                                       
--- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------                                       
a   US           11         20                                                  
b   UK                                 30
```

P.S. As of dynamic pivot - only XML form is available:

```
SQL> with t (SNF, SFCM, POOL, QUOTA) as
  2  (
  3  select 'a','US','eng',11 from dual union all
  4  select 'a','US','sud',20 from dual union all
  5  select 'b','UK','aau',30 from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM t
  8  PIVOT XML
  9  (
 10  SUM(QUOTA)
 11  FOR (pool)
 12  IN (select pool from t)
 13  )
 14  /

SNF SFCM POOL_XML                                                               
--- ---- --------------------------------------------------                     
a   US   <PivotSet><item><column name = "POOL">aau</column>                     
         <column name = "SUM(QUOTA)"></column></item><item>                     
         <column name = "POOL">eng</column><column name = "                     
         SUM(QUOTA)">11</column></item><item><column name =                     
          "POOL">sud</column><column name = "SUM(QUOTA)">20                     
         </column></item></PivotSet>                                            

b   UK   <PivotSet><item><column name = "POOL">aau</column>                     
         <column name = "SUM(QUOTA)">30</column></item><ite                     
         m><column name = "POOL">eng</column><column name =                     
          "SUM(QUOTA)"></column></item><item><column name =                     
          "POOL">sud</column><column name = "SUM(QUOTA)"></                     
         column></item></PivotSet>
```